# I am trying to migrate Vue 2 to vue3 with vue-loader. I am unable to point migration build ('@vue/compat') using vue-loader config

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to migrate Vue 2 to vue3 with vue-loader. I am unable to point migration build ('@vue/compat')

here is my projects files

1. package.json

```
{
  
  "version": "1.0.0",  
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.9.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-virtual-scroll-list": "^1.3.2",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "exif-js": "^2.3.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "js-htmlencode": "^0.3.0",
    "linkifyjs": "^2.1.6",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.28",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-toasted": "^1.1.24",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

2. I have 'Build' folder,in that different config files are there namely vue-loader.config.js, webpack.base.config.js ,webpack.dev.config.js ,e

where do I need to change to point migration build ('@vue/compat')

I tried by using vue cli but is not woking with my project configuration are diffrant

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the vue property in webpack.config.js

```
 alias: {
      vue: "@vue/compat",
    }
```